# Body moves down when Navigation opens (CSS, Javascript)

Tags: javascript, css, html, jquery-animate

I'm trying to create a full size navigation menu for a site. My problem is that the  tag moves down when I open it so I cant position it properly on the page. It's not exactly on the top of the page. Down below you can see my code. 
The menu should cover the whole screen and should not move when it's open.
Would appreciate it if someone can help me.

**index.html**

```
<body>
        <div class="nav" id="nav">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="close" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
                <a href="#">About</a>
                <a href="#">Gallery</a>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>

              </div>

              <span id="open" class="open" onclick="openNav()">&#9776</span>
    <div class="content-wrapper">


    <div class="header-team">

        <img src="img/smoke_team.png">

      </div>
    </div>
      <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
```

**style.scss**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700,800');

$main-font: 'Open Sans';

html,body {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: #000;
}

.header-team {
    display: flex;
    background-image: url("../img/teamimg.png");
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 200px 0px;
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 8em auto 0em auto;
    animation-name: move-in;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    opacity: 0.75;
    justify-content: center;
    z-index: 1;
}

@keyframes move-in {
    from {
        background-position: 200px 0px;
    }
    to {
        background-position: top;
    }
}

.header-team img {
    align-self: center;
    width: 1000px;
    opacity: 0;
    margin-right: 200px;
    animation-name: move-smoke;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes move-smoke {
    from {
        margin-right: 200px;
    }
    to {
        margin-right: 0px;
    }
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 0.9;
    }
}



.open {
    color: grey;
    font-size: 30px;
    float: right;
    margin: 5.5em 1.3em 0em 0em;
    z-index: 99;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    }

    .open:hover {
        color: #a30000;
    }

  .nav {
    text-align: center;
    width: 0%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 100;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    transition: 0.3s;
    display: block;
  }

  .nav a {
    clear: right;
    color: white;
    font-size: 26px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 1.5em 0;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-family: $main-font;
  }

  .nav a:first-child {
      font-size: 45px;
      margin-bottom: -30px;
      margin-top: -40px;
  }

  .close {
    float: right;
    margin: 0em 1em 1em 1em;
  }

  .nav a:not(:first-child):hover {
    color: #a30000;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }
```

**script.js**

```
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("open").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("nav").style.width = "100%";
  }

  function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("nav").style.width = "0%";
    document.getElementById("open").style.display = "block";
  }
```

Comment: Can you make a code example? I will look into it

Comment: I've made a JSFiddle with my code. I don't know if this helps. https://jsfiddle.net/yg1jjg6b
Hope you meant that, I am new to Stack Overflow so sometimes I need a bit of time to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood your question correctly.

To make the `.nav` cover the whole screen and not move, just add

```
top: 0;
left: 0;
```

to `.nav` style.

The layout changes because you are changing `display` property of `#open` span, which interacts with the positions of other elements on the page. You probably are looking for `visibility` css property, which does not mess up the positioning but just says whether the element is visible or not. Change respective lines in `openNav()` and `closeNav()` to

```
document.getElementById("open").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

and

```
document.getElementById("open").style.visibility = "visible";
```

Comment: That solved the problem with the cover of the whole screen. Thank you! But still my `Body`  "element" is moving downwords as soon as I click on the navigation button but that also moves my `.header-team` div. I dont think that's right. Or is it? I mean the div "jumps" a bit.

Comment: So the Navigation should just be an overlay and not move anything

Comment: Great! Thank you for your solution! Learned something new. That worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I hope you get your answer correctly

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("open").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("nav").style.width = "100%";
  }

  function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("nav").style.width = "0%";
    document.getElementById("open").style.display = "block";
  }
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700,800');

$main-font: 'Open Sans';

html,body {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: #000;
}

.header-team {
    display: flex;
    background-image: url("../img/teamimg.png");
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 200px 0px;
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 8em auto 0em auto;
    animation-name: move-in;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    opacity: 0.75;
    justify-content: center;
    z-index: 1;
}

@keyframes move-in {
    from {
        background-position: 200px 0px;
    }
    to {
        background-position: top;
    }
}

.header-team img {
    align-self: center;
    width: 1000px;
    opacity: 0;
    margin-right: 200px;
    animation-name: move-smoke;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes move-smoke {
    from {
        margin-right: 200px;
    }
    to {
        margin-right: 0px;
    }
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 0.9;
    }
}



.open {
    color: grey;
    font-size: 30px;
    float: right;
    
    z-index: 99;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    }

    .open:hover {
        color: #a30000;
    }

  .nav {
    text-align: center;
    width: 0%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 100;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    transition: 0.3s;
    display: block;
  }

  .nav a {
    clear: right;
    color: white;
    font-size: 26px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 1.5em 0;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-family: $main-font;
  }

  .nav a:first-child {
      font-size: 45px;
      
  }

  .close {
    float: right;
    margin: -1em 1em -1em 0em;
  }

  .nav a:not(:first-child):hover {
    color: #a30000;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }

.nav {
  top: 0;
left: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
        <div class="nav" id="nav">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="close" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
                <a href="#">About</a>
                <a href="#">Gallery</a>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>

              </div>

              <span id="open" class="open" onclick="openNav()">&#9776</span>
    <div class="content-wrapper">


    <div class="header-team">

        <img src="img/smoke_team.png">

      </div>
    </div>
      <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
```